# removing words with numbers and letters from command line input in python 3: error

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm having trouble getting regex to remove words that contain digits and letters. I keep getting "TypeError: expected string or buffer" Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

```
$ testing abc
sorted_word = re.sub("\S+\d\S+", "", word_sort).strip()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import re


in_list = sys.argv

def word_sort(in_list):
    word_sort = " 1a "
    word_sort = sorted(in_list[1:], key=len)
    for i in word_sort:
        punctuation = '.',',',';','!',' / ','"','?' #strips punctuation from words
        if i in punctuation: #removes punctuation
            word_sort = word_sort.replace(i," ")
    word_sort= sorted(word_sort, key=lambda L: (L.lower(), L))
    sorted_word = " 1a "
    sorted_word = re.sub("\S+\d\S+", "", word_sort).strip()
    return sorted_word

print (word_sort(in_list))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

`word_sort= sorted(word_sort, key=lambda L: (L.lower(), L))`

iterates through the `word_sort` string but doesn't create a `str` object, just a `list` of the sorted characters, so `re` module chokes on it.

You have to `join` the characters again to recompose the string:

```
word_sort= "".join(sorted(word_sort, key=lambda L: (L.lower(), L)))
```

small tester:

```
>>> sorted("dcba")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> "".join(sorted("dcba"))
'abcd'
```

BTW: you should avoid to call the function and the local variables with the same name `word_sort`. It's difficult to read. And fortunately you don't call your function recursively :)